# Getting Abort trap 6 while coding SLL

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm new to c++. Trying to make a simple singly linked list program. The code is as follows. Here I have created a Node class, SLL class and functions accordingly.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node{

    private:
        int data;
        Node* next;

    friend class SLL;
};

class SLL{
    public:
        SLL();
        ~SLL();
        bool empty() const;
        const int& front() const;
        void addFront(const int& e);
        void removeFront();
        void printList();
    private:
        Node* head;
};

SLL::SLL()
    :head(NULL){ }

SLL::~SLL(){
    while(!empty())
        removeFront();
}

bool SLL::empty() const{
    return head == NULL;
}
void SLL::removeFront(){
    Node* temp = head;
    head = temp->next;
    delete temp;
}

void SLL::addFront(const int& e){
    Node* n = new Node;
    n->data = e;
    n->next = head;
    head = n;
}

void SLL::printList(){
    Node* temp = head;
    // int n =0 ;
    while(temp->next){
        // n++;
        cout<< temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    delete temp;
}

int main(){
    SLL a;
    a.addFront(1); 
    a.printList();
}
```

When I compile the program, getting the following error.

```
ol(36664,0x7fff8a6e0340) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb055402820: pointer being freedwas not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Why is this error appearing? WHat's the solution for this?

Comment: It literally told you how to debug it...

Comment: @UnholySheep, temp is just waste ,so deleting it after printing the list

Comment: `temp` is not dinamically allocated with new keyword, so deleting it gives `SIGABRT`

Comment: [std::forward_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delete temp;` in `printList` doesn’t destroy the *variable* `temp`; local variables are already destroyed automatically.  (Indeed, the technical term is “automatic storage duration“.)  After all, no `delete` is needed (or possible) in

```
void f() {
  int i=std::rand();
  std::cout << i;
}
```

It destroys the *object* `temp` points to, thus corrupting your list.

Use `delete` exactly once per `new`: in this case, that means balancing the `addFront` and `removeFront` (which should make intuitive sense), including in the destructor—which you’re already doing.

Comment: So, when do we actually need to use delete ?

Comment: @bigbounty: When you used `new`. Does your book not explain this? Might be time for a better book!

Comment: "So, when do we actually need to use delete?" - *very* rarely since you should usually be using smart pointers and containers, *not* manual memory management with naked `new` and `delete`.